# Problem Tkinter: How do I resize window correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm learning Python Tkinter, so I made a Pomodoro Timer. It has a expand and shrink mode like this:
[image: Expand Mode]

[image: Shrink Mode]

The button at the extreme bottom right toggles between the modes.
The window opens at expand mode at default. When I shrink for the first time, it shrinks the was it's supposed to. Then after I switch back to expand mode, if I shrink it back, it becomes like this:

[image]
.
Here is my shrink method:

```
def shrink():
    """To generate the minimized window"""
    root.resizable(0,0) #Making the window un-resizable
    root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', True) #To make the window stick to the top
    root.overrideredirect(True) #To hide the title bar
    root.bind("<Button-1>",savelastclickpos)
    root.bind("<B1-Motion>",dragging)
    root['cursor']='fleur'
    img_lbl.grid_forget() #To remove the big image
    title_lbl.grid_forget() #To remove the big title 
    shr_btn.grid_forget() #To remove the shrink button
    root.geometry('400x60') #Changing the dimensions of the window
    global tmt_lbl
    global btn_exp
#-----------------New smaller image------------------#
    tmt_img=PhotoImage(file='./tomato_40x40.png')
    tmt_lbl=Label(image=tmt_img,bg='#ffffff')
    tmt_lbl.image=tmt_img
#----------------------------------------#
    tmt_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=5,sticky='w')
    timer_lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=1)
    btn_frame.grid(row=0,column=2,pady=5,sticky='w')
    btn_exp=Button(image=exp_img,command=expand)
    btn_exp.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky='se')
    btn_exp['cursor']='hand2'
```

Here is my expand method:

```
def expand():
    """To manage the maximized window"""
    root.resizable(True,True) #Making the window resiable again
    root.call('wm', 'attributes', '.', '-topmost', False) #Allowing the window to be hidden
    root.overrideredirect(False) #Making the title bar visible again
    root['cursor']='arrow'
    tmt_lbl.destroy() #Removing the smaller label
    btn_exp.destroy() #Removing the expand button to replace it with the shrink button
    root.geometry('450x310') #Changing the dimensions of the window
    img_lbl=Label(bg='#ffffff')
    img_lbl.image=img
    img_lbl['image']=img
    img_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
    title_lbl=Label(text='Pomodoro\nTimer',font=myfont,fg='black',bg='#ffffff')
    title_lbl.grid(row=0,column=1,columnspan=2)
    timer_lbl.grid(row=1,column=0,columnspan=3)
    btn_frame.grid(row=2,column=0,columnspan=3,sticky='')
    shr_btn=Button(image=shr_img,bd=0,bg='#ffffff',command=shrink)
    shr_btn['cursor']='hand2'
    shr_btn.grid(row=2,column=2,sticky='se',padx=5,pady=5)
```

I'm unable to understand that if it happens flawlessly during the first time, then why does it messes from the second try?

Comment: I see you are creating a new `img_lbl`, `title_lbl`, and `shr_btn` in your `expand` function and then referencing them in your `shrink` function. Creating a variable/object within a function will make it local to that function. I am guessing when you initialize these objects the first time they are in global scope. Then after you expand, you `destroy` them and only initialize them in local scope. That would cause your second call of `shrink` to behave differently then the first call.

Comment: @Axe319 so should I create them once globally, and then I can `pack` and `pack_forget` them ??

Comment: Yes, that's what I would suggest. There are some things you could clean up once you learn about classes and shared state but for the time being that would get it working.